# Post request works in browser but not in mobile apps

Tags: android, .net, web-services, post

We're creating android app, it has a login WebService(http).

The web service is written in .Net, the input and return form of the web service is a json format. When we test the web service in firefox  Rest client add-on the output json file seems to be correct as follows

```
{
  "status": true,
  "statusdesc": "success",
  "userid": "cd2725e7-d0bf-4aac-9e5d-feccd0d40405",
  "password": "w1inHr+gPQd+ijxhIWMH/A=="
}
```

But when I try the same web service in using the following code,

```
try{
            int TIMEOUT_MILLISEC = 30000; // = 30 seconds
            HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);

            SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new CustomX509TrustManager() }, new SecureRandom());

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
            SSLSocketFactory ssf = new CustomSSLSocketFactory(ctx);
            ssf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
            ClientConnectionManager ccm = httpClient.getConnectionManager();
            SchemeRegistry sr = ccm.getSchemeRegistry();
            sr.register(new Scheme("https", ssf, 443));
            DefaultHttpClient sslClient = new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, httpClient.getParams());

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Url);
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
            reqEntity.addPart("data",new StringBody(obj.toString(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);

            HttpResponse response = sslClient.execute(httpPost);
            StatusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            Log.e("Response", "statuscode " + StatusCode);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            Log.e("Response String ",""+entity.toString());
            if (entity != null) {
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

The response seems to be as follows

```
{"userid":null,"password":null,"statusdesc":"Unexpected character encountered while parsing number: Q. Path '', line 1, position 2.\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadNumberIntoBuffer()\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseNumber(ReadType readType)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings settings)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(String json, JsonLoadSettings settings)\r\n   at CommonWebService.WebServiceCommon.ValidateLogin()","status":false,"emailid":null}
```

What is to be the issue in mobile code

Comment: What is the problem for you? The null's or something else?

Comment: when i try in browser result is as status = true, userid seems to be a long character. When i try the same in mobile app it returns as null

Comment: We already knew that. You did not answer my question. `userid seems to be a long character.` ??? Please elaborate.

Comment: `reqEntity.addPart("data",new StringBody(obj.toString(),`. You are only adding a 'data' parameter. Where is the username and the rest? Moreover you did not tell the type of 'obj' and not what the contents might be. And you did not tell how the server wants the data to be posted. Or how you did it in Firefox. In this way its difficult helping you.